# R raster: How to get the extent of raster with value?

Tags: r, r-raster, extent

There is a raster file with three bands. The spatial range of the data includes a large number of valueless areas. How to obtain the extent of the value area？[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `terra::trim` to remove all the outer rows and columns that only have NA values.

Example data

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)

x <- extend(r, ext(c(0,10,40,60)))
plot(x)
```

Solution

```
y <- trim(x)
plot(y)
```